# How to customize the height of expanded content in Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

- When click headers to expand/collapse content that is broken into
  logical sections,
         But those section's have some default height defined .Suppose i have to give a fixed
         height i.e 200px .How can we customize the height that is expanded after the click
         of header i.e Section 1 and Section 2

  ```
  <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-
         ui.css"           
         />
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

       </head>


        <div id="accordion">
         <h3>Section 1</h3>
         <div>
             <p>
             Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
             ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
             amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
             odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
             </p>
         </div>
         <h3>Section 2</h3>
         <div>
             <p>
             Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
             purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
             velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
             suscipit faucibus urna.
             </p>
         </div>

        </div>​
     </html>
       javascript:-
       $(function() {
             $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
         });​
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If content height is your concern you might take a look at "heightStyle" property,
Or if you want to use custom height logic, can use the "beforeActivate" event. The event fires before activating a tab. so in this event height changing can be possible.

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        beforeActivate: function(event, ui){
            $(ui.newPanel).css('height', '20');
        }
    });   
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for answering.But what i want that content height should have a fixed height means all expanded content should have fixed height i.e 200px. If content goes more into it  then it should turn into scrollable.Because in future how much content i have to add into a section that i cant predict now.so scrollable is als0 necessary.

Comment: i think you can tweak around this example: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace. notice the outer container has a fixed height of 220ox. and the whole accordion is contained in it with scrollbar.

Comment: i tried to do what you suggested but i'm not able to figure out what exactly the problem is in my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZJJM6/1/
This is my code. Please help me in getting my answer :)

Comment: yes, i want the same functionality as in the example that you suggested .